# ASP MVC Javascript link to uri

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application and have a link that can be either a url or link to a file (network share, location file system)

Here is my html....

```
<span id="link_id">link</span>
```

Here is my jQuery / Javascript......

```
jQuery('#link_id').live('click', function() {
    var location = jQuery(this).attr('link');
    window.open(location, '_blank');
});
```

However, I can getting an error when the link is not an web address starting with http://.

Is there a way to accomplish this so I can access web urls AND shared drives?

Comment: So is it fare to assume that this is an intranet site?

Comment: Also why not use a standard `a` tag for this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

First of all, 'link' is not an attribute of `<span>` tag, so you can't use it like `.attr('link');`. I would try something like this: 
`

```
    jQuery('#link_id').live('click', function() {

    var location = jQuery(this).text();
    var httpFoundAt=location.search("http://");
    var httpsFoundAt    =location.search("https://");

        if ((httpFoundAt==-1) && (httpsFoundAt==-1) )
        {
            location='file://' + location;

        }

    window.open(location);
});
```

You can check for "www" instead of http or https depending on your use case.

Comment: that does not work.  For instance if the url is www.google.com it will give me an error because it thinks its is a relative path inside my asp.net mvc application.

Comment: I need someway to determine if a string is a url or directory/file/share path